# How to update column values with a sub-string of its original value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update the column values (of pandas dataframe) as follows:

`1234(456` should become `1234`

`abcde(fg` should become `abcde`

I wrote the following code, but for some reason it is not working:

```
energy[(energy['Country'].str.contains('\(')) &
       (energy['Country'] != np.NAN)
      ].apply(lambda x: x['Country'].split('(')[0])
```

Here is the error: `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`

Any ideas to refine my code and make it work?

Comment: You can't use `!=` to test for NaN.  Use `.isnull()` or `.notnull()` instead.

Comment: Maybe `energy['Country'].dropna()[(energy['Country'].str.conta......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have a `DF` similar in format as yours:

```
energy = pd.DataFrame(dict(Country=[np.NaN, '1234(456', 'abcde(fg', np.NaN, 'pqrst'],
                           State=['A','B','C','D','E']))
energy
```

[image]

Let's see the first part of the boolean mask created:

```
mask1 = energy['Country'].str.contains('\(')
mask1
0      NaN
1     True
2     True
3      NaN
4    False
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

When you try to use this mask, you get:

```
energy[mask]
```

> `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`

which is evident as there are both bool and float dtypes present concurrently.

Also, the second mask:

```
mask2 = energy['Country'] != np.NAN   # --> In python, the Nan's don't compare equal
mask2

0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: Country, dtype: bool
```

You can clearly see that eventhough we've created a mask, there are some Nan's present which aren't converted to their boolean types.

***approach 1:***

One hack would be to set the default values of `NaN` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) as `False`, like:

```
mask = energy['Country'].str.contains('\(', na=False) # 
mask
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: Country, dtype: bool
```

Then, use it like:

```
energy[mask].apply(lambda x: x['Country'].split('(')[0], axis=1)
1     1234
2    abcde
dtype: object
```

***approach 2:***

Another way would be use `dropna` and then create the mask:

```
mask = energy['Country'].dropna().str.contains('\(')
mask
1     True
2     True
4    False
Name: Country, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
         Country
0      1234(456)
1  abcde(fg xxxx

In [24]: df.Country.str.replace(r'([^\(]*).*', r'\1')
Out[24]:
0     1234
1    abcde
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It replaces with the first string if ( is in the string else it returns the original.

```
energy['Country'] = energy.apply(lambda x: x['Country'].split("(")[0] if "(" in x['Country'] else x['Country'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got this error: `<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: Good answer, except it should be `energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].apply(lambda x: x.split("(")[0] if "(" in x else x)` Then again it will perform much slower than @MaxU's answer, precisely because that answer is vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.split('(')[0] if '(' in x  else x)
```